# using the output of a regex as the input of another regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have some text which I want to extract only the digits from, and then apply a formatting filter to it.

For example,

```
 //extract only the digits
 TheText = TheText.replace(/\D/g, '');

 //apply formatting pattern
 TheText = TheText.replace(/(\d{1})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5')
```

Basically, the output will look like this:

```
1 23 45 67 89
```

How can I combine these regular expressions into just one?

Thanks.

Note: I'm not looking to chain the statements using .replace(...).replace(...) statements, just the regex.

Comment: Do you mean `text.replace(..).replace(..)`? Or do you mean combining the regex?

Comment: If I may ask, why are you using regex for this? It seems simpler to me to use a loop to build the result string.

Comment: I meant combining the regex!

Comment: Then why didn't you ask that? Or maybe try to be more clear.

Comment: @frenchie we need examples of the input strings to craft an appropriate regex for you.  Might be as simple as `/(\d{1}).*(\d{2})?.*(\d{2})?.*(\d{2})?.*(\d{2})?/`, but there's no way to be sure

Comment: What about adding start `^` and end `$` characters to your regex? Then it'll only accept numbers in that exact format.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @ExplosionPills: the input can be anything, all I want to keep are the digits and then apply the formatting.

Comment: but you're not giving us an example @frenchie. you underestimate the nature of the problem.

Comment: Why do you need it in one regex?

Comment: @Plasmarob: then take a look at this jsFiddle; I'm building a regex from several jQuery and regex expressions http://jsfiddle.net/D6cZz/5/

Comment: What are using it for? All that is is a running piece of code I could have wrapped it in. If that helped it would have been in your question.

Comment: @Plasmarob: I'm using it to validate a French phone number.

Comment: Nothing to get excited over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Least clever way: extract each digit separately.

```
.replace(/\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*/,
"$1 $2$3 $4$5 $6$7 $8$9")
```

Comment: that would work, but he's not clarifying how many there will be. does anyone know an any-number of matches way?

Comment: If you need an any-count match, then your format probably isn't a finite string, and I think that's a sign that you need to step back (your XY problem, Plasmarob).

Comment: i couldn't have put it better.

Comment: Actually, I only need the first 9 digits so you're close!

Comment: Then finish the job! I would be unhappy with this solution, though.

Comment: @Plasmarob: anyway, can you answer the question?

Comment: State the actual problem you're trying to solve. You're not trying to solve "how do I make a single regex that acts like these two regexes together?" You're trying to extract the first nine (or fewer?) digits from a string and place them in a format or something, and you want one regex for some unknown but vital reason.